# Disappearing texture after automatic rig in maximo

Tags: rigging

I made a rig using maximo software for a figure I built in blender. But when I returned the figure to blender after building the rig all the texture disappeared from the figure.
How can you easily return the texture to the figure?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures